# Is it possible to send information from an O3 core's load queue all the way to a Ruby state machine?

Tags: gem5

I am writing a custom cache coherence policy where the state machine invalidates local cache lines on a write, but will behave differently based on whether or not there's already a load for that same line in the load queue of at least one O3 core.

Basically, the state machine should send the invalidation, wait for a response from the load queues, then go into one state or the other based on the response.

Is there an easy way to send a snoop response from the LSQ if the L1 cache causes an invalidation on one of its stored loads?